# .htaccess redirect folders with except one folder

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect the folowing type of folders: `example.com/stores/something/title/` to
`example.com/stores/title/`. I made the following redirection:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /stores/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) http://www.example.com/stores/$2/$3
```

It works however I have a problem: I don't want to redirect these kind of links:

```
example.com/stores/title/page/2/
```

My redirection redirect the above link to `example.com/stores/2/`. So I want to redirect everything except there is a "page" subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule .*/page/.* - [L]
```

should do it. It should appear above the other rules.

Comment: it doesn't work. somehow this cancel rewrite rule have no effect on redirectmatch 301

Comment: You insert this line before `RewriteMatch`?

Comment: Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule .*/page/.* - [L]

RedirectMatch 301 /sitemap\.xml$ http://www.mywebsite.com/sitemap_index.xml
RedirectMatch 301 /sitemap\.xml\.gz$ http://www.mywebsite.com/sitemap_index.xml
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)/robots\.txt http://www.mywebsite.com/robots.txt

Comment: RedirectMatch 301 ^/tag/$      http://www.mywebsite.com/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/search/$   http://www.mywebsite.com/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/category/$ http://www.mywebsite.com/
RedirectMatch 301 /stores/(.*)/(?!page)(.*)/ http://www.mywebsite.com/stores/$2

</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negative-lookahead to make sure the third parameter isn't "page"

```
RedirectMatch 301 /stores/(.*)/(?!page)(.*)/(.*) http://www.example.com/stores/$2/$3
```

Comment: it doesn't work either. store/something/page/2 still redirect to store/2